# In what order do I consume the Blame! universe?

Tags: blame

I recently stumbled upon the [Blame!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6574146/) movie on Netflix. I eagerly watched it, enjoying every minute of it - not least for the underlying amazing world. I realized that it was based on the [manga of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blame!) and looked it up.

Now there's more than just the manga, to my knowledge there is:

- [Blame! (Manga)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blame!)
- Blame!² (Oneshot?)
- [NOiSE (Manga)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOiSE)
- [NSE: Net Sphere Engineer (Manga?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blame!#NSE:_Net_Sphere_Engineer)
- [Blame! (ONA)](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1166)
- [Blame! Prologue (ONA)](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11305)
- [Blame! (Movie, 2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6574146/)

In what order should I best consume these works? And am I missing any more of them in this list?

Answer (score 2):

You can start reading the original sources. The other works is just like a side-story, not really canon (as far i know, the side story is just an "explanation chapter" or a filler chapter about the Blame! universe that never explained before in the original ***Blame!*** manga, based on Wikipedia and myanimelist. I have never read those side-story, nor try it ).

**Main story**

- [Blame! (manga)](https://myanimelist.net/manga/149/Blame)

**Side-story (not recommended, but you can give it try)**

- [NOiSE](https://myanimelist.net/manga/465/NOiSE)
- [Blame Gakuen! And So On](https://myanimelist.net/manga/17368/Blame_Gakuen_And_So_On)

The Blame! movie only cover some part like:

1. Cibo first appearance : Volume 2, Chapter 9.
2. the rest : Volume 5 - Volume 6, Chapter 26 - Chapter 34.

In your question, you put the ONA version of Blame!, and looks like it's a clip of Blame! anime but i never heard about those ones. There is no anime adaptation of Blame! until Netflix made one.